# How do I not die from lasers?

Tags: sega-genesis, syndicate

In *Syndicate* (1993) on Sega Mega Drive (Genesis), in the later missions the enemy agents are armed with lasers that can kill your agent with one shot. Worse, sometimes they take out more than one agent with a single shot when you have them in group mode. When this happens all the mods and weapons your agents were carrying are lost. I never had enough money to equip a new team and try again.

How do I get through the later missions and clock the game?